# how to enumerate like this picture below?

Tags: enumerate

[image: The image below are lool like this:]

```
2.
  2.1
  2.2
3.
  3.1
  3.2
  3.3
4.
5.
  5.1
  5.2
```

how am I going to display this in Latex I've tried the {enumerate} and {procedureflow} but nothing happened. I need help. Thank you :)

Comment: Please have a look into `enumitem` package ;-)

Comment: Please leave a feedback on the solutions here

Answer (score 8):

Same as Christian's answer, but with the correct `enumitem`'s syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label*=\textcolor{blue}{\arabic*.},ref=\theenumi]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\textcolor{green}{\arabic*.},ref=\theenumi.\arabic*]
    \item First First
    \item Second Second
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the colors, it's even simpler

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.,ref=\theenumi.\arabic*]
    \item First First
    \item Second Second
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `ref=` arguments are needed to print the correct number in case you reference the items with labels.

Comment: I am always confusing the position of the `*` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Never mind, I hope you get the tick for your answer. :-)

Comment: The solution with the color changes has the (likely unwanted) side-effect that cross-references to enumerated items will also use color. In running text, it's probably better *not* to experience such color changes.

Comment: @Mico: That's true but we all fell into a trap ;-) The OP did not want that colour change at all

Comment: @karlkoeller: Very unlikely: I answered another question by the OP some time ago... she never accepted it or gave feedback ... I fell into another trap... Meanwhile I think Mico's approach is the better one

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - How do you know the OP is female?

Comment: @Mico: I assumed from the profile photo ... and a photograph does never lie ;-)

Comment: @Mico Added `ref=` arguments to avoid that.

Comment: +1 for adding the `ref=` part. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The `enumitem` package is very useful for such changes of enumeration labels.

The standard setup involves a `[label={\arabic*}]` setup to show the labels as arabic numbers, but it could be `[label={\alph*}]` as well. This uses the current counter of the enumeration level.

Please note, that `[label*={\arabic*}]` is possible too, as it appends the label to the parent label.

**Edit** As requested, without the colour

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\theenumi.\arabic*.}]
    \item First First
    \item Second Second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: without the color?

Comment: @JensenRuedas: Why did you not say this in your question?;-)

Comment: Im sorry . I forgot

Comment: still need package installation.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I cann't complile. I got ! Missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: @minthao_2011: I will have a check -- I had a typo.

Comment: @JensenRuedas If your TeX distribution misses `enumitem` it's time to upgrade it.

Comment: @JensenRuedas Could you please accept Christians's answer so to mark the question as solved? It is easy. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: @karlkoeller: No, the OP should accept your solution, it's more elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Or without the package (modified from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures)

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.}
\makeatletter\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.}\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item First First
    \item Second Second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

Comment: You may want to add the instructions `\makeatletter` `\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.}` `\makeatother`, in case there's a chance that the OP wants to cross-reference one or more of the second-level items.

Comment: Thanks @Mico.  I'd never needed to do that before, but it's a good addition.